# azure AD and graph access - angular front end and laravel php backend

Tags: angular, laravel, azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I have an angular front end and laravel api backend and I want to allow users from my internal app to login using their microsoft details but I also want to use the laravel authentication functionality as well.

Should i be able to install the msal javascript library on my angular app, have the user go through the popup or redirect flow to get an access token, pass that token to my api and then the api can query the azure/graph api's using that token?

Answer (score 3):

You should create the authentication functionality through laravel backend.

Msal javascript library is only for the Single Page Applications.

You can read about authentication flows with tutorials and code samples in MS docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-overview

Besides that, Laravel has two packages for Azure AD authentications:
https://github.com/metrogistics/laravel-azure-ad-oauth - Extension of Socialite
https://github.com/rootinc/laravel-azure-middleware - Based on middleware

There is a lot of information about how to work with MS Azure AD authentication on the https://laracasts.com/

Comment: My front end angular application is a SPA hosted on www.myapp.com and laravel backend is at api.myapp.com. Ideally I want to authenticate the user on angular to get an access token and then pass that to laravel api so it can pull the user data. Is this possible?

Comment: @the-a-train In my opinion, the right flow is through backend in this example.
But also, I have questions:
- Do you have any other authentication method outside Azure AD on your side (backend)?
- Are you keeping your users data within some database on backend?

Comment: Yes. Currently my backend has a users table and I have a rest endpoint that takes a username and password and returns a jwt token. I want to introduce ad auth that is only available for users within my company’s tenant (user@mycompany.com) but still retain the existing method for other users.